# Should my fan have been installed off center?

Tags: ceiling-fan, installation, patio, structure

We recently had a Duralum freestanding patio cover installed. There's electrical running through the structure, and a light/52 inch fan coming down from the ceiling.

The fan was installed 11 inches off center. It's noticeable to me, especially when sitting at the table, and it's frustrating to me. It took me a while to figure out why they installed it where they did, and then I figured it out. The Duralum product's ceiling is made up of 4 foot panels that are snapped together. The center of the structure would be about 6-8 inches off of the seam between two panels, so they installed the fan in the center of one of the panels instead.

If this product requires the fan to be installed in the center of a panel, then in my mind, they should have placed and centered the panel that would be holding the fan, and built out from there. Instead, they placed a panel at one end, then just snapped them together until they reached the other end. The last panel was cut down to size. If they were to fix this, they'd need to disassemble a good portion of the structure since everything is connected together.

I have a few questions:

- Is it appropriate to install something like a ceiling fan off center without first speaking with the customer and getting their approval?
- Does it seem like it would be required to install the fan in the middle of a panel? Does that give it any more structure/stability?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have it in the contract that the fan in centered?  or a drawing?   You as the homeowner and the payer of the bill have the right to have the job done to your specification.  Get them to come back and put the fan on center.  Would you be alright if the fan was off center in that panel in order to center it in the space?  That way they wouldn't have to pull and re hang the whole ceiling.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks. I only have a rough drawing on graph paper from their estimate. I’d rather argue about “being on Center” being assumed and standard before I use that as my justification but I guess I always have that.

Comment: Yes, CLEARLY on center is standard.